Request not going via proxy
Anyone know why I am unable to use a proxy in requests?
This is my code
import requests

def check_proxy_usage():
    current_ip = requests.get('https://api.ipify.org').text
    print(f"Current IP Address: {current_ip}")

    proxy = {'http': 'http://51.89.14.70:80'}

    try:
        response = requests.get('https://httpbin.org/ip', proxies=proxy)
        response_data = response.json()
        response_ip = response_data['origin']
        print(f"Response IP Address: {response_ip}")
        if current_ip == response_ip:
            print("The request was not sent via the proxy.")
        else:
            print("The request was sent via the proxy.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

check_proxy_usage()


output:
Current IP Address: 157...... #my ip
 Response IP Address: 157...... #my ip
 The request was not sent via the proxy.

I don't know anything else to try.

An http proxy will not have any effect on an https request.

so it means its literally not possible to send request to https using http proxy in any language or library

How the ... did you interpret this into my comment? You have to set an https proxy, which might have an http address btw.

proxy = {'http': 'http://51.89.14.70:80', 'https': 'http://51.89.14.70:80'}
